# Help in understanding if any rules is being broken here

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079964/how-did-we-get-the-different-values-used-in-murmurhash3-how-does-it-guarantee-l and I see people down-voting it, I am trying to understand if there is any rule of the site that I have broken. I am not saying that I am in the right or wrong here, just wanted to check if there is some rule that is broken.

I went through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and couldn't find any rule that is broken.

Comment: We do chat really well. Comments don't do chat really well. Let's use comments for clarifications, not arguments.

Answer (score 8):

I can see why your post was closed as too broad and I agree with it. I also think there is a little bit of unclearness as well. First your title:

> How did we get the different values used in MurmurHash3? How does it guarantee low collision? What is the mathematics behind it?

That's three different questions. It doesn't seem to me that they are really different, as they could all be related and answering one will answer the other two as well, but it raises a red flag. Then we have:

> I have googled about MurmurHash3, seen both the pseudo code and the page of the author. Both the pages explain what the algorithm does but not how the algorithm works.

My response to this is: "Okay the guy wants to know how the algorithm works." Instead, you then say:

> The intent of my question "how did we get the different values used in MurmurHash3" is not how it was generated but why those methods of generation were chosen and how it guarantees a low collision intuitively explained.

So, now I'm left to think that you don't care how the algorithm works, but you want to know why the implementer chose to implement it the way he did.  Someone out there might know the reason, but without the implementer saying why, IMHO the answers would all be guesses. That to me makes a vote-to-close as *too broad* totally acceptable.

You then finish with:

> Its fairly easy to understand what is being done but not why it is being done.

This again reaffirms at least to me, that you want to know why the implementer chose to implement it the way he did.

This may not be what you meant it to be, but that is how I interpret it and in the end that is what it boils down to, the interpretation of the question by the reader.

Comment: The problem that you have in the question seems to be in the second paragraph, where in what I am asking is not what the author thought or not which algorithm was chosen to generate the values (which is there on the site) but how the algorithm chosen to generate the values help in MurmurHash3 and how it ensures low collision. What more do you think is needed to help you understand the question and improve the question?

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM That may be what you meant to ask but to me that is not what you asked.  Maybe you should edit that into your question to make it more clear.  I am trying to point out reasons why I would VTC and I suspect other felt the same way.  The gist of what I am saying is you need to explain your question better so we know its exact scope.

Comment: Doesn't why those methods were chosen mean why those methods help in finally help in getting the right hash with low collision? Is the confusion or ambiguity due to the word chosen?

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM I've explained my confusion in the answer with my reaction to your second paragraph.  Until your question does not read like you want to know why the implementer implemented the algorithm the way he did then to me it is too broad.

Comment: And my question is would removing the word "chosen" there help remove the ambiguity? ie would "used" or some other word be a better candidate?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would have to see how you change it.

Comment: I have changed it.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM Well it can always be reopened if it's whipped into shape.  Unfortunately it still reads as why did he do this.  I have to sign off now so this will be my last comment of the night,

Answer (score 5):

Your question *looks like*

```
 Searched alot. 
 Request to explain following code in great details. 
 Wall of code without any sources/attribution.
```

There is no indication of any effort to understand code. It absolutely does not matter if you did a lot of work - if it is not shown in the post it did not happen. There are tons of questions like that and most get similar negative votes.

I don't know how you would show your research effort, but in 10-20 seconds regular person would spent on evaluating the post there is *nothing stands out* that shows your effort.

I.e. since SO is code and programming related site I'd be completely intrigued by something like

> "tried this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code in C with different values but results look like similarly good hash function according to [What is a good Hash Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function)".

Comment: First in the comments it was that my question was too broad, after that there is no indication that I did work? What do you want me to put, screenshot of google search?

Comment: Is this line not enough? "I have googled about MurmurHash3, seen both the pseudo code and the page of the author. Both the pages explain what the algorithm does but not how the algorithm works." Do you want me to post the links too? and that magically makes the question better? The pseudo code I read is there in the post and I exactly know what is being done there, not why it is being done. If these things doesn't indicate effort, I don't know what does. I don't agree with this answer. You are just trying to prove your point and making bad points while doing that.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM Yes, I just trying to clarify my point of view. I don't want to prove anything, nor expect you to agree with it. I'm not really sure why you've asked question so if you are looking for answer that you agree with - you may as well provide your own explanation as answer so people can vote on it too.

Comment: First you come up with a reason that it is too broad then you come up with an answer that there is no proof of effort. Do you really think only links will give a proof of effort or indication of effort? Or that putting source or attribution will mean that a person has put effort? How would you say that indication of effort has to be shown? Is there any explicit rule regarding what needs to be put to show effort?

Comment: My point is that all I see you doing is try to prove that it is wrong, over giving what rule is actually broken. For what reason I can't say, but you are trying to think of random points to try and prove that I am wrong. While this itself is not a wrong thing to do, it shows bias on your part. Secondly, I am looking for things I agree with, it has to be logically true if I have to accept it, but that doesn't mean I have a presumption of some sort that I am right, the logic that is given is something that I have to agree with at the end of the day.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM "does not show research effort" *is* the reason to downvote. There are more reasons provided in comments/answers. I don't know how you would show your research effort (i.e. I'd expect "tried this MCVE code with different values but results look like similarly good hash function according to XXXX") but in 10-20 seconds regular person would spent on evaluating the post there is nothing stands out that shows your effort.

Comment: I don't really see what can be shown as research effort apart from stating that I have gone through the different explanations of the algorithm and not able to get why it works. I did post the pseudocode too, and I can post the link as well but I don't really think that confirms my research effort any more than me telling that I have read and know what is being done.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM  'I don't really see what can be shown as research effort' - there is nothing.  Posting your research notes so far would be, (presumably), tl;dr and a simple claim to have read and analysed all the easily available papers will be met with disbelief.  So, if you have done your diligent research, you cannot demonstrate it.  So, your question is too broad and/or off-topic.

Comment: "So, if you have done your diligent research, you cannot demonstrate it" what logical statement is this? If I have done diligent research why can't I demonstrate it? This is not a paper I am working on, I was just reading an algorithm for my own interests, the author nor the website pointed to any prior paper as far as I saw, so I asked if any one was here who could help me with it, I don't see how that is a problem. And if they have posted and I missed it, someone could have simply pointed it out, doesn't show that I haven't done any effort. Irrational attempts to prove I am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the part that made me feel like your question was too broad:

> The intent of my question ... is not how it was generated but why those methods of generation were chosen and how it guarantees a low collision intuitively explained.

We didn't implement the hash so we can't tell you why that is.  The only real way to get that sort of answer is to track down the creator, or search for discussions on the hash leading up to this point.

Comment: If only the implementor has to explain why then most of the questions on SO shouldn't be accepted. There can be others who might have understood the algorithm who can explain. This is not a logically strong argument.

Comment: I don't deny that an answer from the creator explaining this would be incredible, but at the same time, those are still implementation details that *they* themselves would have to disclose.  It's unrealistic to expect us to be able to explain why they made that decision.  As for other questions:  I prefer to take that on a case-by-case basis, but most of the questions (at least in Java, which I haunt) that ask "why" can generally be answered with references to the JLS or source code comments.

Comment: Let us take a simple algorithm f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2), I don't have to talk to fibonacci to understand how this works. Going a few steps ahead, if many people have accepted murmurhash3 to be a strong algorithm it means that they have understood why it is strong and they can answer it. It doesn't have to be a subjective answer because why they understood it is strong is not based out of feelings or emotions but they can understand it from the mathematics behind it, which is what I was looking at. It isn't too broad because I am asking about that specific algorithm.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM:  The Fibonacci sequence has *scores* of books, journals, papers, and proofs concerning it; that is to say, the wealth of information on it is already so vast that it's not hard to find information on it.  But math and software implementation are different; if you need to know *why* a particular decision was taken then the author of the code is the best source.  If it's not provided, all we can realistically do is grasp at straws.

Comment: Proof for fibonacci number or do you mean proof for what can be done using fibonacci number or relating to fibonacci number, because fibonacci number itself is defined that way and we don't need proof for it. I agree on the software implementation part but the question like how a formula works or how f = ma, need not take into consideration what the author thought while he invented the formula. Frankly I am not interested in what the author thought but I am more interested in how or why it works, which I am sure many people who use the hash might have figured out already.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM: [Proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+proof&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=fs&trackid=sp-006&gws_rd=ssl) as in definition 1.

Comment: @KenWhite you mean "evidence or argument establishing a fact or the truth of a statement."?

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM: Yes, which is the meaning to which Makoto was referring. There are scores of documented proofs (evidence establishing a fact) regarding Fibonacci. There are no such proofs of why the implementor of MurmurHash3 chose the algorithms without asking that implementor directly. We certainly cannot speak to why that person made that choice, and any attempt to do so would be mere speculation. I don't see *Questions asking for speculation* anywhere in the guidelines for what's on topic at SO.

Comment: establishing a fact regarding fibonacci means proof related to fibonacci numbers and not proof of fibonacci numbers, which is not required since fibonacci numbers is defined that way. I wanted to clarify that so the question to him. "There are no such proofs of why the implementor of MurmurHash3 chose the algorithms without asking that implementor directly" but those who use the algorithm do know why those algorithms can provide values which finally give low collision can't they? Otherwise only the implementor has understood the algorithm and no one else.